# Запуск приложения с параметром

Tags: java, python

Есть приложение написанное на `Python`. С помощью `argparse` я обрабатываю параметры. Причем есть 2 парсера, зависящие от первого параметра (было "-URL_TR" или "-DSN_TR"). Приложение конвертировано в .EXE . Если запускать руками - все хорошо.

Есть приложение на `java`. В нем я запускаю приложение выше.Запускаю так:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\adr\\pril.exe", "-URL_TR", "-par 1");
pb.inheritIO();
pb.start();
```

И вот тут он ругается что первого параметра нет.

```
usage: pril.exe [-h] {-URL_TR, -DSN_TR}...
pril.exe: error invalid choice: '-par 1' (choose from '-URL_TR', '-DSN_TR')
```

Comment: могу только предположить, что первый параметр пропускается так как считается именем запускаемой программы. а как в питоне параметры получаются?

Comment: @Grundy тут скорее тараканы связанные с самим ProcessBuilder. Я продублировал первый параметр - и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: то есть вот так `new ProcessBuilder("C:\\adr\\pril.exe", "-URL_TR", "-URL_TR", "-par 1");` тоже не сработало?

Comment: Я именно так сейчас и сделал. Сейчас землю убрал, пересоберу и попробую так.

Comment: землю убрал? о_О

Comment: _ этот знак. И да, эффект АБСОЛЮТНО такой же, но когда я убрал тире перед тригером, ошибка изменилась. Теперь он ругается на все параметры. (там их много "-par 1", "-par2 1" и т.д.)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34818/discussion-between-grundy-and-rihard-brugekhaim).